# Display all $scope variables in View - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to dump and display all properties of the $scope object in the view ( HTML Page) for debugging purposes in AngularJS.

Comment: Your browser has a console with a JavaScript debugger

Comment: Is that the only way .  no way to dump all of $scope in view and inspect whats there and whats not there?

Comment: The latest Chrome browser has this ability right out of the box.

Comment: what Phil said below, plus use angular batarang (the last stable release)

Comment: thanks. figured to use the console.

Answer (score 7):

If you really need to dump it out to the view, you can use this

```
<pre ng-repeat="(key, val) in this">{{key}} = {{val|json}}</pre>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/2zKgX1g7NeeBJiehgyky?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

There are many browser plugins out there for this. One i am using in safari is called ng-inspector. You can find similar plugins for all the major browsers. If you want to do it manually, inspect an element(you will see $0) and in the console, do `angular.element($0).scope()` . It will display your `$scope` object in the console

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code to this,
in Your Controller

```
 var self =  this;
self.name = 'World';
self.foo = [1,2,3,4];
self.bar = {
"foo": "foo",
"bar": "bar",
"baz": "baz"
};
$scope.value = self;
```

Here is Plunkner URL http://plnkr.co/edit/DmWTnK300imIYyDVQ0ME?p=preview